# The "there are already 30 answers" message shouldn't override the "you already answered this" message

Tags: feature-request, answers, warning, multiple-answers

When you try to post an answer to a question that already has 30 answers you receive the following message:

> This question has more than 30 answers already.
>
> Did you read through all the existing answers first to make sure your answer will be contributing something new?
>
> Also please note that you can click the edit link on any of these answers to improve them.

[image: Screenshot of message]

When you try to post an answer to a question that you have already posted an answer to, you receive the following message:

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
>
> You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

[image: Screenshot of message]

When a question already has 30 answers **and** you have already posted an answer to that question... only the first message displays.

The fact that there are already 30 answers doesn't change the fact that you have already answered it, and should probably consider editing your existing answer. Of course, given that there are also 30 other answers you should probably check those out as well before posting another one, but that is *an additional concern*.

Is it possible for both messages to be displayed in such situations? Alternatively, is there a reason why one was chosen to override the other? (Perhaps because if you check out the other 30 answers you will by definition also check out your existing answer?)